# C++ what happen to reference when a vector resize its capacity?

Tags: c++

Let's assume we have a reference to an element in a vector. (I'm not sure about what happen behind reference, but I guess the reference holds the pointer to the exact element.)

And we keep pushing things into that vector, then it reach its capacity, then resize itself. What happen in resizing is that it might ask for a new space in the memory, and then copy the original data to the new space. And now the memory which the reference point to become undefined.

I'm not sure if my guess is right. Could this happen? Or my understanding is wrong.....If that's the case, then using reference to container's element might be dangerous...

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012451/how-to-tell-if-stdvector-resized-itself-and-how-to-account-for-pointers-to-va

Comment: When a `std::vector` is resized, all pointers, iterators, or references to elements are invalidated.  Using them gives undefined behaviour.    Practically, you may get lucky (e.g. depending on when resizing involves a change of capacity versus when it doesn't) but there is no guarantee of that, and relying on it is a good way to achieve bugs that are quite difficult to track down.

Comment: When a `std::vector` is resized, pointers, references and iterators to elements are invalidated and you must obtain new ones.

Comment: Addition to @Peter's point: if you specifically ensured the capacity would be sufficiently large prior to pushing new elements, then it's not getting lucky, and you are guaranteed that there will be no reallocations.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, when vector capacity is increased, new memory is allocated and all references/pointers/iterators to the vector elements are invalidated.

Comment: The duplicate is a proper answer. This is/should be, just a comment.